# How to install driver/.inf file during setup with NSIS?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, nsis, device-driver

currently I use a NSIS script which installs a device driver/.inf file this way:

```
File /r "mydriver.inf"
File /r "mydriver.cat"
nsExec::ExecToStack 'pnputil -i "mydriver.inf"'
```

This works smoothly with Windows 7 - when the user first connects the device, it is already known to the system and the correct driver is applied automatically.

Now I found that no longer works with Windows 8.x, here the user has to go to device manager, click the new device and point it to storage place of .inf/.cab files manually.

So how can this be done better? How can I let Windows 8 know about this driver so that it uses them automatically once the device is connected?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you write this driver?

Comment: Anders: no, it is only an .inf file that itself points to the standard serial interface driver - just with an other VID/PID. .cab file is already signed, so that's not the problem

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `pnputil -a -i "c:\full\path\to\myinf.inf"`?

If you did not write this driver then you should ask the people that wrote it.

This is not really a NSIS specific question so you might want to reformat the question a little bit so the NT driver gurus can find it. You might also have more luck if you try the [MSDN driver dev. forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/home?category=windowshardwaredev) and/or the [OSR list](http://www.osronline.com/cf.cfm?PageURL=showlists.cfm?list=NTDEV)...